# Laravel : how to show author name in post list datatables

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, relation

I want show author name in post list with datatables (yajra)

Post Model:

```
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'post_author');
}
```

User Model:

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class,'post_author');
}
```

PostController:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $data = Post::select('post_id', 'post_title', 'post_author')->get();
        return Datatables::of($data)
            ->addColumn('action', 'backend.columns.postsColumn')->rawColumns(['action'])
            ->make(true);
    }
    return view('admin.post.index');
}
```

How to show author name instead of number in columns?

index.blade.php :

```
columns: [
       {data: 'post_id', name: 'id'},
       {data: 'post_title', name: 'post_title'},
       {data: 'post_author', name: 'post_author'},]
```

Answer (score 3):

you can join you table and select the user name too ...

```
$data = Post::join('users','users.id','posts.author_id')
        ->select(['post_id', 'post_title', 'post_author','users.name as authorName'])
            ->get();


columns: [
       {data: 'post_id', name: 'id'},
       {data: 'post_title', name: 'post_title'},
       {data: 'post_author', name: 'post_author'},
       {data: 'authorName', name: 'authorName'},
]
```